# How long does it take to move into silver league?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am rank 3 in my bronze league division in Starcraft 2. I just played a 4v4 quick match with 2 gold players and 1 silver player on my team, and 2 golds/2 silvers on the other team. And I wasn't the worst player on the list post-game, either. When will I be moved into Silver league?

Comment: You have different ratings for 1v1 and 4v4...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Battle.net keeps a hidden rating called "MMR", which is similar to an ELO rating used in chess and other games. When you win a match, your MMR increases. The better your opponent, the more in increases by. When you lose a match, your MMR decreases in a similar fashion.

In order to be promoted,

1. Your MMR must elevate so that it's well into the next league
2. Your MMR must be "stable" so bnet can have confidence that you will stay in the new league once promoted

And note that even if you meet these criteria, the promotion itself may not happen right away. The internal statistics in battle.net are ever-changing, and as such not all calculations happen in real-time. For example, you may win 50 games in a row against gold leaguers and not be promoted. Wake up the next morning, play one game and be promoted.

The best guide to how this works is on Team Liquid: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=195273

Comment: That's a very helpful explanation. I'll take a look at the TL link you provided. I was in the past in silver league and then in a new season got put into bronze after the placement matches and have since been wondering why I haven't been promoted back into Silver.

Comment: It can definitely be confusing because the leagues have very little to do with promotions. So even if you win against a bunch of gold players, maybe they were all close to being demoted too, so their MMR is in the bronze league. But the good news is that it should not affect your decision making. Always try to play your best, and let promotions / demotions come and go :)

Comment: One addition to this excellent explanation: MMR changes depend solely on wins & losses. Neither your post-game score, nor any in-game events, are taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a win loss ratio better than 50%. Your Position in your Division isn´t really a clue. There is a lot of math behind the ladder system including the bonus-pool etc... If you really want to get deeper into this, try [this wiki](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/League_%28StarCraft_II%29)

There you will find a link to [this chart](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/3947374/Climbing_the_Ladder_How_to_Earn_a_League_Promotion-11_15_2011#blog) in the official battle.net blog. Maybe these two articles will help you more than I can ;-)

Answer (score -2):

If the ladder system puts you in teams with gold/silver, it means it already considers your level to be gold/silver. However league changes occur only at the end of a season.

"Each season will now last for approximately two months." according to blizzard, so just wait for the next season.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, you *can* get promoted during the season.